# CSS alignment change in IE browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

In my website all by CSS alignment is totally changed in IE10. If I disable compatibility mode in IE10, then it works fine.
How to disable compatibility mode through my HTML code?

Comment: May be you should declare a <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: but still i getting same error

Comment: Try setting <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />. But in IE10+ compatibility mode is ON for local/intranet sites by default

Comment: In other words, your website is also broken in real browsers like Chrome, Firefox, etc? Well, that's not exactly a JSF problem as it's merely the HTML code generator here. Just fix the HTML doctype and rewrite the CSS according web standards. Related read: http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in `head` tag.

```
!--  Force IE to use the latest version of its rendering engine -->  
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

By telling IE to use the latest version of its rendering engine in your page.

Comment: @praveenraj4ever can you explain more?  works in IE8 means, you're using it from IE 10 browser?